# Subtracting from array just deletes previous 2 characters?

Tags: php

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to subtract 1 from a number. This number is stored in an array. The array is formed by reading a line from a text file, splitting it by "|" and then storing it into an array.

The text file looks like this:
100|2

Here's my code:

```
function remove1($key, $privorno=0) {
  $actualFile = file_get_contents("users/" . $key . ".txt");
  $numtoremove = explode('|', $actualFile);

  if($privorno == 1) {
    file_put_contents("users/" . $key . ".txt", $numtoremove[0] . "|" . $numtoremove[1] - 1);
  } else {
    file_put_contents("users/" . $key . ".txt", $numtoremove[0] - 1 . "|" . $numtoremove[1]);
  }
```

When this executes it leaves the text file as just "100" (I.E Deleting the 2 and the "|")

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The number is being stored as a string. You can use intval() to treat the values as an integer

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised, that you get 100 in your file. So I put a simplified reproducer on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/EAhoZ). For you if branch it prints 99 (not 100), but it seems to remove `|2`.

This can be explained by the operator precedence in PHP ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)). Both `.` and `-` have the same priority, and they are **left associative**. This means that the string `100|2` gets created first, and then PHP tries to subtract 1, which should result in 99.

As I said, I don't know why you get 100, but maybe you can get your program to work as intended by adding parentheses in the right place:

```
file_put_contents("users/" . $key . ".txt", $numtoremove[0] . "|" . ($numtoremove[1] - 1));
```